# How to maintain order for word to index mapping in pyspark for array of token features?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, nlp, deep-learning

Here is a use case I am looking for with pyspark. I currently have a dataframe with word tokens and want to build a vocabulary followed by replace word with the index in the vocabulary. Here is my dataframe

```
>>> wordDataFrame.show(10, False)
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                            |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
|0  |[hi, i, heard, about, spark]                     |
|1  |[i, wish, java, could, use, case, spark, classes]|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+
```

When I use the CountVectorizer

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import CountVectorizer
cv = CountVectorizer(binary=True)\
  .setInputCol("words")\
  .setOutputCol("countVec")\
  .setToLowercase(True)
  .setMinTF(1)\
  .setMinDF(1)
fittedCV = cv.fit(wordDataFrame)
fittedCV.transform(wordDataFrame).show(2, False)
+---+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|id |words                                            |features                                                 |
+---+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
|0  |[hi, i, heard, about, spark]                     |(11,[0,1,6,8,9],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])                   |
|1  |[i, wish, java, could, use, case, spark, classes]|(11,[0,1,2,3,4,5,7,10],[1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])|
+---+-------------------------------------------------+---------------------------------------------------------+
```

Next here is how my vocabulary looks like

```
>>> from pprint import pprint
>>> pprint(dict([(i, x) for i,x in enumerate(fittedCV.vocabulary)]))
{0: 'i',
 1: 'spark',
 2: 'wish',
 3: 'use',
 4: 'case',
 5: 'java',
 6: 'hi',
 7: 'could',
 8: 'about',
 9: 'heard',
 10: 'classes'}
```

What I am looking for is this

```
[hi, i , heard, about, spark] -> [6, 0, 9, 8, 1] instead of [0,1,6,8,9]
```

Basically maintaining the order of the token. I tried looking in the documents but looks like all of the vectorizer lose position. For my case I need to maintain position as this feature will go into a LSTM layer further downstream

Answer (score 0):

I recently had a use case similar to yours. I ended up using `StringIndexer`:

```
l = [
  (0, ["hi", "i", "heard", "about", "spark"]), 
  (1, ["i", "wish", "java", "could", "use", "case", "spark", "classes"])
]
wordDataFrame = spark.createDataFrame(l, ['id', 'words'])
wordDataFrame.show()
```

.

```
+---+--------------------+
| id|               words|
+---+--------------------+
|  0|[hi, i, heard, ab...|
|  1|[i, wish, java, c...|
+---+--------------------+
```

.

```
from pyspark.ml.feature import StringIndexer

# define indexer
indexer = StringIndexer(inputCol="word_strings", outputCol="word_index")

# use explode to map col<array<string>> => col<string>
# fit indexer on col<string>
indexer = indexer.fit(
  wordDataFrame
  .select(F.explode(F.col("words")).alias("word_strings"))
)

print(indexer.labels)
```

.

```
['i', 'spark', 'heard', 'classes', 'java', 'could', 'use', 'hi', 'case', 'about', 'wish']
```

.

```
indexedWordDataFrame = (
  indexer
  .transform(
    # use explode to map col<array<string>> => col<string>
    # use indexer to transform col<string> => col<double>
    wordDataFrame
    .withColumn("word_strings", F.explode(F.col("words")))
  )
  # use groupby + collect_list to map col<double> => col<array<double>>
  .groupby("id", "words")
  .agg(F.collect_list("word_index").alias("word_index_array"))
)

indexedWordDataFrame.orderBy("id").show()
```

.

```
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
| id|               words|    word_index_array|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
|  0|[hi, i, heard, ab...|[7.0, 0.0, 2.0, 9...|
|  1|[i, wish, java, c...|[0.0, 10.0, 4.0, ...|
+---+--------------------+--------------------+
```

HTH